# Making text appear over time with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple web page when I ran into a problem that I might need everyone to help me solve. Say I was writing some text in font, and I want 
text to appear right under it under 10 seconds. Is this possible? I've tried Google already. It's results weren't so decent.

Comment: RandomAnswer - yes it is possible.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: "appear right under it" <-- what is "it" exactly? how to "appear"?

Comment: Under "it" means under the <font> tag. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Don't use the <font> tag

Comment: Err... Could you suggest any other way to show text using HTML? I'm pretty sure <pre> won't help...

Comment: @RandomUser You could always use a `<span>` tag....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question was not very clear, I guess this might (or might not) be what you are looking for:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('element').innerHTML += '<br>More text';
}, 10000);
```

```html
<div id="element">Some text</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `setTimeout` be better since the interval will continue adding more text every 10 seconds?

Comment: @NewToJS Check again ;)

Comment: Occam's razor: +1

Answer (score 0):

Kinda rough, but gets the point across if what you want is text to display directly under some other text. (However, looks like you simply wanted a paragraph line break using `<br>`.)

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    var _text = document.getElementById('text-over'),
        under = document.createElement('span');

    under.className = 'text-under';
    under.textContent = 'Under';

    _text.append(under);
    
    console.log(_text, under);
}, 10000);
```

```css
#text-over {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.text-under {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span id='text-over'>Text</span> will go under there.
</p>
```

Comment: @Duncan Luke, your answer was mostly what I was considering. But maybe without the more text. How would that be done?

Comment: I think you meant to post that under the other answer.

Comment: @RandomUser Please add an example to your question to clarify what exactly you are looking for

Comment: @Jared Farrish; your coding has a error. Try running the code on Stack Overflow's engine. It reports an error.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, what I need help with is that something (most likely text) would appear under everything in the <body>, and it would be easy for me to add the coding in the <head>.

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: text.append is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 30,
  "colno": 10
}

Comment: @RandomUser - You can try it now. That would indicate it wasn't finding the element by `id`. Refresh the page, I edited the code several times, maybe it's still giving you an old version.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations):

```css
.more {
  animation: fadein 10s steps(1, end);
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div>Some text</div>
<div class="more">Some more</div>
```

Comment: @RandomUser The same thing as what?

Comment: Oops... Sorry about that! It wasn't the same thing, whatever I was talking about! :)